# Variable length arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class which defines few global variables as below:

```
namespace Algo
{
    public static class AlgorithmParameters
    {
        public int pop_size = 100;

    }
}
```

In my another csharp file, which also contains the main(), and in the main() I am declaring an array of type structure and the array size as pop_size but I am getting some error on `"chromo_typ Population[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];"`. Please find the code below. Am I using a incorrect syntax for array declaration of variable length size??

```
namespace Algo
{
    class Program
    {
        struct chromo_typ
        {
            string   bits;  
            float    fitness;

            chromo_typ() {
                bits = "";
                fitness = 0.0f;
            }

            chromo_typ(string bts, float ftns)
            {
                bits = bts;
                fitness = ftns;
            }
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                chromo_typ Population[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.

Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't specify the size when you declare the variable, you specify it when you create the instance of the array:

```
chromo_typ[] Population = new chromo_typ[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];
```

Or if you separate the declaration and creation:

```
chromo_typ[] Population;
Population = new chromo_typ[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];
```

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Algo.AlgorithmParameters.pop_size'

Comment: You need to make pop_size static, eg, `public static int pop_size = 100;`

Comment: ohh ok I changed pop_size to static int... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change the initialize in this way:

```
        //while (true) ///??? what is the reason for this infinite loop ???
        //{ 
            chromo_typ[] Population = new chrom_typ[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size] ; 
        //}
```

also you need to change pop_size to a static because is declared inside a static class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have to use a while(true)

But in any case, to declare array, you have to do this:

```
chromo_typ[] Population = new chromo_typ[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];
```

and also you have to declare the member pop_size as static in AlgorithmParameters

```
public static class AlgorithmParameters
{
     public static int pop_size = 100;
}
```

Comment: One more thing, struct cannot have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the initialization statement as below, it will create an instance

```
chromo_typ[] Population = new chrom_typ[AlgorithmParameters.pop_size] ;
```